# Nested Layouts ... Drawn stacked not layered

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Ok ... I am missing it.   I am trying to have a Dialog created that has a `GridLayout` with a number of CheckBox's and below that a Accept, Close PushButton in a `HBoxLayout`.  But with the following code all I see is the `GridLayout` on top of `HBoxLayout`.  Why? How can I dimension the dialog to the width of the GridLayout?

```
class CheckerDialog(QtGui.QDialog) :

    def __init__(self, parent, headers) :
        super(CheckerDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        checksLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.cbList = []
        i  = 0
        for y in range(13):
            for x in range (9):
                if i == len(headers) : break
                cb = QtGui.QCheckBox(headers[i], self)
                cb.move(OFFSET_X + SPACER_X*x, OFFSET_Y + SPACER_Y*y)
                self.cbList.append(cb)
                i += 1

        buttonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        applyButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Apply")
        closeButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Close")
        buttonLayout.addWidget(applyButton)        
        buttonLayout.addWidget(closeButton)
        self.connect(applyButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self._apply)
        self.connect(closeButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.close)

        checkerLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        checkerLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        checkerLayout.addLayout(checksLayout)
```

Comment: OK . solved ... sorry for the trouble ... needed a self. on the checkerLayout.  And needed to do a self.setLayout(self.checkerLayout).

Comment: If your solve by self, please post your answer. to close unanswered it. thanks.

Comment: Actually I need to amend it.  There is still an error.  Will edit the main to clarify.

Comment: Error ? 'self.setLayout(checkerLayout)' isn't solve your problem or your have more problem?

Comment: Well - it presents both layouts --- true.  BUT!  As stated above .... the HBoxLayout is ON TOP of the GridLayout - not beneath it.   And the size of the GridLayout does NOT control the size of the overall Layout, which I want it to do!

Comment: "the HBoxLayout is ON TOP of the GridLayout - not beneath it." >> That true, your code is doing that your set buttonLayout of beuuton before checksLayout, It should not beneath it. "And the size of the GridLayout does NOT control the size of the overall Layout" >> It yes, because your not add widget of QCheckBox in checksLayout, I suggest to read reference for add your widget on checksLayout. >>>
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. the HBoxLayout is ON TOP of the GridLayout - not beneath it.

Yes, it should be in your code. Sequence has effect in your code.

```
    checkerLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout) # <- TOP
    checkerLayout.addLayout(checksLayout) # <- BOTTOM
```

If your want to set widget by specifies index, your can use `QBoxLayout.insertLayout (self, int index, QLayout layout, int stretch = 0)`;

```
    checkerLayout.insertLayout(1, buttonLayout) # <- BOTTOM
    checkerLayout.insertLayout(0, checksLayout) # <- TOP
```

---

> 1. And the size of the GridLayout does NOT control the size of the
>      overall Layout,

Yes, it should be in your code (again). because your not put check box in `QGridLayout`. Your just set geometry on root layout not `QGridLayout`. Pleas use `QGridLayout.addWidget (self, QWidget, int row, int column, Qt.Alignment alignment = 0)` to add widget specifies index (x, y);

Little example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCheckerDialog (QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None) :
        super(QCheckerDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        checkBoxQGridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        for y in range(13):
            for x in range(9):
                currentQCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox('%d, %d' % (x, y))
                currentQCheckBox.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
                checkBoxQGridLayout.addWidget(currentQCheckBox, x, y)

        buttonQHBoxLayout  = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        applyQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Apply')
        closeQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Close')
        buttonQHBoxLayout.addWidget(applyQPushButton)        
        buttonQHBoxLayout.addWidget(closeQPushButton)

        allQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        allQVBoxLayout.insertLayout(1, buttonQHBoxLayout)
        allQVBoxLayout.insertLayout(0, checkBoxQGridLayout)
        self.setLayout(allQVBoxLayout)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQQCheckerDialog = QCheckerDialog()
myQQCheckerDialog.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

See also:

[QBoxLayout.insertLayout (self, int index, QLayout layout, int stretch = 0) Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qboxlayout.html#insertLayout)

[QGridLayout.addWidget (self, QWidget, int row, int column, Qt.Alignment alignment = 0) Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2)